# What is なく doing in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, literature

While reading the light novel for 君の名は I came across this sentence in the first chapter:

> 私は大切な誰かと隙間なくぴったりとくっついている。

Is using `なく` here equivalent to using `ないで` or does it have a different meaning altogether?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The なく is the 連用形 of ない used in the sense of:

> 10 名詞に付いて、否定の意を含む形容詞をつくる。「こころ―・い」「違い―・い」「面目 (めんぼく) ―・い」　([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162263/meaning/m0u/))

ない can be attached to a noun, forming an i-adjective with a negative meaning ("without~~"). A few more examples: 「[絶]{た}え[間]{ま}ない」「休みない」「[跡形]{あとかた}ない」「[相違]{そうい}ない」

[隙間]{すきま}なく in your example is the 連用形, or the adverbial form, of 「隙間ない」, i.e. 隙間+ない.

Examples: 「絶え間なく」「休みなく」「跡形なく」「[余念]{よねん}なく」「[仕方]{しかた}なく」

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

It's come to my attention that the answer by @Chocolate is a much more grounded answer than mine, and admittedly this was the first time I've learned about such a structure in grammatical terms (noun + なく = adverb).

In light of that, I offer my original answer **a** (not **the**) way a Japanese language learner can remember or reason out what `noun + なく`probably means.

In my personal experience, as a non-native Japanese language learner never having studied the `noun + なく` form from a book, `noun + が + なくて` has always been the way I've mentally reasoned out what `noun + なく` means while communicating with native speakers. One of the first things I (and likely many other Japanese language learners) learned when starting out was the existence of `noun + が + ない`, so from that building block I would deduce the meaning of `noun + なく`

In practice it's always helped me correctly understand at least the big-picture meaning, but apparently not the standard grammatical basis.

### Original answer

> 隙間なく

means

> 隙間がなくて

隙間 is a noun, so the conjugation ○○ないで isn't applicable.

Comment: でも・・・「私は大切な誰かと隙間**が**なく**て**ぴったりとくっついている。」とは言い換えられませんよね・・・

Comment: @Chocolate さんの回答を読んで勉強になりました。私は文法的に分析すると、多くの英語表現みたいに「正しくなくはないけど実際は使ってみるとやっぱりおかしい」と思っていたのです。それにしても今まではオリジナルの説明で何となく意味がわかってきて、ネイティブじゃない人としての考え方の一つだとこの回答を編集しました。

Comment: * ...多くの英語表現みたいに、この場合は「(名詞)がなくて」というパターンが「正しくなくはないけど実際は使ってみるとやっぱりおかしい」...

Comment: I think て is extra and "a noun + なく" and "a noun +がなく" are mostly interchangeable.