# 〜なく〜: シャワーではなくお風呂に入ります。

Tags: grammar

Could someone please explain how なく is being used here? Is it the te-form of 無い?

> 日本では多くの人がお風呂に入ります。シャワーでは**なく**お風呂に入ります。

Comment: Are you sure it's not なくて?

Comment: @Nameless I've seen both ではなく and ではなくて used in sentences like these, it's fine.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3439  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59605  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93181

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/74247/9831